# If everyone in the world chooses a random real number between $0$ and $1$ one by one, how many times will a world record for lowest number be set?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value, approximation

I have a random number generator that generates a random real number between $0$ and $1$ at the press of a button. All 8 billion people in the world line up for a try. Occasionally a world record for lowest number is set. (The first person automatically sets the first world record.) Approximately how many times will a world record be set?

Let $n=8\times 10^9$, the world's population.

**Approach 1**

Let $f(n,k)=$ the number of permutations of the first $n$ positive integers with exactly $k$ numbers that are less than all previous numbers. The first number in any permutation is considered to be less than all previous numbers (in the sense that it sets a new low).

The probability that exactly $k$ world records will be set, is $\frac{f(n,k)}{n!}$.

Then the expected number of world records is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\left(\frac{f(n,k)}{n!}\right)$.

But I do not know how to express $f(n,k)$ so that I can calculate the expectation. Maybe there is a smart way to express $f(n,k)$, like [stars and bars](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html).

**Approach 2**

If I roll a six-sided die $m$ times, the expectation for the number of sixes is $m\times \text{(probability that the $k$th throw is a six)}=\frac{m}{6}$.

Similarly, perhaps the expectation for the number of world records can be approximated as $n\times \text{(probability that the $k$th person sets a world record)}=n\times\frac1k$.

But the problem is that $\frac1k$ is not a constant. However, suppose we use the average value of $\frac1k$, which is $\frac1n \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac1k \approx \frac1n \int_0^n \frac1x dx=\frac{\ln{n}}{n}$. Then the expectation would be $n\times \frac{\ln{n}}{n}=\ln{n}\approx 22.8$.

I tested this approach on excel, and it seems to yield reasonable results. But it seems rather hand-wavy.

**Context**

This question was inspired by a question about the [sine of integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4624239/among-the-first-n-positive-integers-approximately-how-many-m-are-there-such).

Comment: This has been asked before, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541254/expected-value-and-variance-of-records)

Comment: For $f(n,k)$ in Approach 1, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4625477/398708) is more information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We invoke the indicator function trick. Let $X_k$ denote the random number generated for the $k$th person. Then we observe:

> The $k$th person sets a the world record if and only if $X_k$ is the smallest among the first $k$ numbers $X_1, \ldots, X_k$.

Consequently, the number $N$ of times world record is set can be written as the sum

\begin{align*}
N
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}\{\text{$k$th person sets a world record}\} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}\{\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_k\} = X_k\}
\end{align*}

Then by the linearity of expectation, we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[N]
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{1}\{\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_k\} = X_k\}] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{P}(\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_k\} = X_k) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}
= H_n,
\end{align*}

where $H_n$ denotes the $n$th harmonic number.

Comment: Just in time with your edit :-).

Comment: Say the first person 'rolls' the value $0.2$. The next person then only has probability $0.2$ of getting a lower value, not $1/2=0.5$. I don't see why each summand should be $1/k$

Comment: @FShrike It remains a fact that the second person has probability $0.5$ to set a record. There is no need to look at conditional probabilities. Linearity of expectation also works if there is no independence.

Comment: @FShrike But if you examine all possible values that the first person could get, you'll find that on average the second person will set a record half the time. Basically, the second person is equally likely to have the smallest of the two numbers as the largest.

Comment: @FShrike, This problem becomes quite complicated if you try to analyze the occurrences (with each occurrence being a new world record) in the language of arrival process like in your comment. When you are only interested in the expected number of occurrences, however, the indicator trick allows us to not consider the correlation of different occurrences.

Comment: So we would expect about $21$ world records to be set.

Comment: @SangchulLee Hmm. So it is a general fact about independent (uniform?) distributions that $\mathrm{Pr}(\min\{X_1,\cdots,X_k\}=X_k)=\frac{1}{k}$. I see it now, it wasn't clear to me why that identity was true at first but it's obvious from symmetry.

Comment: @Dan, I would say it is more like $H_{8\cdot10^9}\approx 23.38$. Also, If I remember correctly, $N$ behaves like a normal distribution with mean $H_n$ and variance $H_n$ for large $n$. So we may approximate the probability that $N$ lies within some range.

Comment: @FShrike, You are right. In general, if $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ is a sequence of i.i.d. r.v.s with the common distribution having a density function, then for any permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $$\mathbf{P}(X_{\sigma(1)}<X_{\sigma(2)}<\ldots<X_{\sigma(n)})=\frac{1}{n!}$$ by the symmetry. In other words, each possible permutation of "ranks" occurs with equal probabilities. This does not hold in general when $X_k$'s have discrete distribution, though.

Comment: @SangchulLee, Ah yes, about $23.38$. (I thought my computer was finished calculating, but it wasn't.)

Answer (score 3):

1st one has a probability 1 to establish a world-record ; 2nd one has a probability 1/2  to establish a world-record ; k-th one has a probability 1/k to establish a world-record. Total is $\sum_{k=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{k}$

Comment: Your answer is okay, but things will be more clear if you present this sum of probabilities as an expectation.

Comment: I like this answer also. Very elegant.