# How many permutations of the first $n$ positive integers have exactly $k$ numbers that are less than all previous numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

Let $f(n,k)=$ the number of permutations of the first $n$ positive integers with exactly $k$
numbers that are less than all previous numbers. The first number in any permutation is considered to be less than all previous numbers (in the sense that it sets a new low).

> Is there an easy way to calculate $f(n,k)$ in general?

For example, we can show that $f(4,3)=6$ by listing the permutations. (In each permutation, the numbers that are less than all previous numbers are in red.)

$\color{red}3,\color{red}2,\color{red}1,4$
$\color{red}3,\color{red}2,4,\color{red}1$
$\color{red}3,4,\color{red}2,\color{red}1$
$\color{red}4,\color{red}2,\color{red}1,3$
$\color{red}4,\color{red}2,3,\color{red}1$
$\color{red}4,\color{red}3,\color{red}1,2$

I'm looking for a smart way to calculate $f(n,k)$, maybe like [stars and bars](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html).

Context: This is related to "Approach 1" in my question about [world records](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4625434/398708). But I find the question here interesting by itself.

Comment: Don't know abt a "smart" way, but there is an obvious recurrence relation $f(n,k) = f(n-1,k-1) + (n-1)f(n-1,k)$ for $k < n$. Combining it with $f(n,n) = 1$ you can compute this function at least for small $k$ and $n$ without explicit enumeration of permutations.

Comment: You can see Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Foata's_transition_lemma) for a proof that this is counted by the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statistic you are counting is called left-to-right minima.

We have the following linear recurrence $$f(n,k)=f(n-1,k-1)+(n-1)f(n-1,k).$$

Familiar as the recurrence for the unsigned Stirling number of the first kind.

Comment: I think there's a typo in the recurrence in the last term.

Comment: Yeah, I had $n+1$ in mind and wrote for $n$. My bad.